# My c program is generating a segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This method is generating a segmentation fault. The method is meant to return the value at a specified position of a list. The list is a list of polynomials. It should return a polynomial. I tried using gdb on it but it just told me what method it was in.

```
llink* get_specific(llist* node)
{
    struct link * poly;
    int i;
    printf("Which polynomial do you want: ");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    llist* current;
    current = node;
    int j;
    llist* temp;
    for (j = 1;j < i;j++)
        current = current->next;
    poly = current->poly;
  return poly;
}
```

Edit:After fixing the mistake with j and no longer allocating the memory, this code runs fine the first time but gives a fault if I run it a second time

Edit2:

```
 for (j = 1;j < i;j++)
        current = current->next;
```

The segmentation fault is being caused when it accesses the line inside the for loop. If the user input is 1 it runs fine but if it is anything else the fault appears

Comment: Your pointer/malloc-usage is not ok. Neither is your debugger usage, the scanf, etc. ...

Comment: Gdb will tell you the exact line number (and offending instruction). Compile with debug info (-g).

Comment: gdb is not giving me back an exact line number and I have compiled with -g.gdb gives me back #0 0x08048c4d in get_specific () #1 0x08048df3 in main ()

Answer (score 3):

`for (j == 1;j < i;j++)`

should probably be

`for (j = 1; j < i; j++)`

Answer (score 2):

1. make a `NULL` check for `llist* node`
2. No need to allocate `llist* current` [`llist* current = malloc(sizeof(llist));`]
3. `for (j == 1;j < i;j++)` should be `for (j = 0;j < i;j++)`
4. before dereferencing, check `NULL` for `current` in `current->next;`

Note: do not cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has memory leaks.

For example you allocate a node but  it is not used and the memory is not freed

```
llist* current = malloc(sizeof(llist));
current = node;
```

Write the function simpler

```
llink * get_specific( const llink *node )
{
    size_t i;

    printf( "Which polynomial do you want: " );
    scanf( "%u", &i );

    while ( node != NULL && i-- ) node = node->next;

    return node;
}
```

Also there are three different types in your code: `link`, `llink` and `llist`. I do not know what they mean so I used only one type llink in my function. At least it points you the right direction how the function should be written.:)

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code. I suspect the segmentation fault is because you're not initialising your `j` variable. The initialisation clause in your `for` loop is actually a comparison operator. It should probably be `j = 1` (or possibly `j = 0`) rather than `j == 1`.

A fault could also happen if the number entered by the user is past the end of the list. You need some kind of test within the loop to ensure you don't go out of bounds.

It's also worth noting that it doesn't look like you actually need those `malloc` calls. You don't actually seem to be using the memory you've allocated (and you're not freeing it either, so it will be leaking).